# How is possible obfuscate a local var?

Tags: c++, string, obfuscation

If a password is stored in the source file, programs like strings or objdump can easly read the strings and so the password.
My questione is about storing the data like this piece of code:

```
    to_send[77] = data[0];
to_send[27] = data[1];
to_send[4] = data[2];
to_send[777] = data[3];
```

Where data is a string randomkey and to_send is the string to send.
In C++, is possible that an attacker can read easly this debugging the code like a string?
Or is more difficult?

Comment: are you familiar with the dictum ["security by obscurity"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) and its implications?

Comment: Is it possible just hard-code the password-hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make reverse engineering more difficult, you should use DES3 encription, or some similar approach. Any kind of hardcoded data can be "scrambled" that way. Of course, since the key would also be hardcoded, it can be cracked. But, there is no bullet proof solution. You can just play with the level of cracking complexity because once you will have raw decrypted data in the memory.

Comment: And what's the command, like using objdump, to read for example to_send[x]?

Comment: @user1056635 Debuggers like Olly, WinDbg and IDA Pro are used for such purposes.

Answer (score -1):

You have few ways of doing this

1) Md5

Don't save the password in resouces, save a MD5(access_password).
When user enters password test if `MD5(entered_password) == MD5(access_password)`

pro: even if someone reverse your code and find your MD5, it's hard to reverse that value and fins the password (if the password used is not a dictionary word )

2) non-secured but simple way

`char pass[] = {'p','a','s',s'};`

This somehow leated with the version you have tried.
It's quick and simple, your password will not be found with ResHacker because pass will not be stored as a compact block of memory in your exe

3) Using Cryptography to save the password